# I am not able to see x-y-axis labels and annotation_logticks in my graph, any suggestion?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Updated code, i am trying to figure out with both x-axis and y-axis do not appear. I also want y-axis in log scale, and x-axis is natural scale. I tried to clean up variables but still does not work. Any suggestion?

This is how my code looks like:

```
r_blade_mp_25 <-c(0.9996, 1, 1, 1, 0.999945, 0.99988, 0.9996)
p_blade_mp_25 <- c(1559.18, 1410.15, 1492.67, 1439.17, 1518.26, 1533.52, 1559.18)
r_blade_mp_50 <-c(0.999578, 1, 1, 1, 0.999942, 0.999884, 0.999578)
p_blade_mp_50 <- c(1558.91, 1331.39, 1492.01, 1418.74, 1517.34, 1533.35, 1558.91)
r_blade_mp_75 <-c(0.999573, 0.999699, 0.999893, 0.999929, 0.999896, 0.999835, 0.999573)
p_blade_mp_75 <- c(1544.27, 1036.09, 1436.59, 1197.41, 1465.64, 1521.52, 1544.27)

x_blade_mp_25 <- c(25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25)
x_blade_mp_50 <- c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50)
x_blade_mp_75 <- c(75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75)

df_blade_mp_25 <- data.frame(x_blade_mp_25, r_blade_mp_25)
df_blade_mp_50 <- data.frame(x_blade_mp_50, r_blade_mp_50)
df_blade_mp_75 <- data.frame(x_blade_mp_75, r_blade_mp_75)

df_blade_mp_25_power <- data.frame(x_blade_mp_25, p_blade_mp_25)
df_blade_mp_50_power <- data.frame(x_blade_mp_50, p_blade_mp_50)
df_blade_mp_75_power <- data.frame(x_blade_mp_75, p_blade_mp_75)

thresholds_reliability <- ggplot() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_point(data=df_blade_mp_25, aes(x=x_blade_mp_25, y=1-r_blade_mp_25, color = "#2fdac6"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=df_blade_mp_50, aes(x=x_blade_mp_50, y=1-r_blade_mp_50, color = "#bb8fce"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=df_blade_mp_75, aes(x=x_blade_mp_75, y=1-r_blade_mp_75, color = "#e38b27"), size = 3) + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = scales::math_format(format = log10), oob = scales::squish_infinite) +
  #scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') + 
  labs(x = "Threshold aggressiveness", 
       y = bquote("Failure Probability" ~ (P[f])), 
       title = "Google Traces", 
       color = "Deployments") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#2fdac6", "#bb8fce", "#e38b27"),
                     labels = c("25%", "50%", "75%"))
thresholds_reliability

#thresholds power consumption at 25%, 50%, 75%, 90%
thresholds_power <- ggplot() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_point(data=df_blade_mp_25_power, aes(x=x_blade_mp_25, y=p_blade_mp_25, color = "#2fdac6"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=df_blade_mp_50_power, aes(x=x_blade_mp_50, y=p_blade_mp_50, color = "#bb8fce"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=df_blade_mp_75_power, aes(x=x_blade_mp_75, y=p_blade_mp_75, color = "#e38b27"), size = 3) + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = scales::math_format(format = log10), oob = scales::squish_infinite) +
  labs(x = "Threshold aggressiveness", 
       y = bquote("Failure Probability" ~ (P[f])), 
       title = "Google Traces", 
       color = "Deployments") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#2fdac6", "#bb8fce", "#e38b27"),
                     labels = c("25%", "50%", "75%"))
thresholds_power
```

[image]

Comment: What is sim_1 ..... sim_6 in the dataFrame. Please provide a reproducible sample.

Comment: sorry, code is now updated

Comment: I hope it worked for you as well. If it worked I would request you to give an upvote for the answer.

Comment: does not work, i have run other simple plots and it does not work either.

Comment: I ran the script in my environment. It works fine

Comment: is there any way to clean up all the enviroment? some cache or something like that? i dont know why im having this issue...

Comment: Before starting to execute the script, it is a best practice to do this. rm(list = ls()) to clear the environment

Comment: Actually your script also works very well. I checked it just now. I was in a dilema that it doesn't work and that's why you posted this question. Please check by clearing the environment variables.

Comment: still does not work :(, could u try out with this new code that now i updated?

Comment: Can you show me all the packages used in the script? The script works fine!

Comment: it worked finally! i just uninstalled R from win10 and then installed again, reboot system, run section and x-y-axis appeared. anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the script found below like this

```
lifetime_blade_mp <- ggplot() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold", hjust = 0.5)) + 
  geom_point(data=df_trace_1, aes(x=lifetime_blade_mp, y=1-trace_1, color = "#28b463"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=df_trace_5, aes(x=lifetime_blade_mp, y=1-trace_5, color = "#e74c3c"), size = 3) + 
  geom_point(data=df_trace_6, aes(x=lifetime_blade_mp, y=1-trace_6, color = "#f4d03f"), size = 3) + 
  scale_y_log10(labels = scales::math_format(format = log10)) +
  labs(x = "Lifetimes of servers (days)")+ 
  labs(y = bquote("Failure Probability" ~ (P[f])))+ 
  labs(title = "Google Cluster Data 50% thresholds", color = "Deployments") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#28b463", "#e74c3c", "#8e44ad"),
                     labels = c("Google Trace #1", "Google Trace #2",
                                "Google Trace #3"))
```

It is working fine. [image]